# Is there a way to increase Binary Array capacity in ray/pyarrow?

Tags: pyarrow, ray

Is there a way increase `BinaryArray` limit in `pyarrow`? I'm hitting this exception when using `ray.get`:

```
Capacity error: BinaryArray cannot contain more than 2147483646 bytes, have 2147483655
```